# reading a line from a file using a method

Tags: java, file, file-io, readfile

I'm working on a project for university and I'm having some problems when it comes to understand how does a class with a method to read given by our professor works. 
We are supposed to be able to use that method to read words in lines from a text file. However, I don't really understand how it works. If anyone could help me, as well as explaining to me how can I use it to read the files, I'd be so grateful.

Here's the class with the method called read() as well as the methods and variables used by it :

```
public static final char blank = ' ';
public static final char endOfSequence = '\n'; //the lines in the file end with '\n'
private static final int MAX = 20; 
public static char[] letters;
public static int length; 
private static char letter = ' ';
private static char[] phrase = null;
private static int index;

public Word() {
    letters = new char[MAX];
    length = 0;
}
public static Word read() {
    Word wd = new Word();
    jumpBlanks();
    while ((letter != endOfSequence) && // Sequence hasn't finished
            (letter != blank)) { 
        wd.letters[wd.length] = letter;
        letter = readCharKeyB();
    }
    return wd;
}
public static void jumpBlanks() { //reading blanks until finding a word
    while (letter == blank) {
        letter = readCharKeyB();
    }
}
static public char readCharKeyB() {
    char res = '.';
    if (phrase != null) {
        res = phrase[index++];
    }
    return res;
}
```

I have to use it, as I said, to read lines from a file that looks like this:

```
t1 #n name #d address 
t2 #n name #d address
...
```

I have to check first how the line starts (t1, t2, t3) then I have to read the name, between #n and #d, and then the address, between #d and \n. And I have to use that class above with those methods.

This is what I have so far, but doesn't work:

```
public static void generador_de_cartas() throws Exception {

FileReader fr = new FileReader("datos_clientes.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = br.readLine();
        char [] linea = line.toCharArray();
        while (line != null){
            linea=Word.leer(); //I don't know how to use it properly

            line=br.readLine();
        }


        br.close();
        fr.close();
    }
```

Please, could someone explain to me how the method works and how can I make it work for reading a file so I can figure out how to use it?

Thanks!

Comment: All those `static` are making my eyes hurt. Your constructor seems to set variables, but all your methods and variables are `static`. If your professor wrote that, get a new one.

Comment: Fire your professor. He is just trying to murder java, and it's rich api.

Comment: so I should change letters and length to non-static, right? @Boris

Comment: I don't see these functions taking input as string anywhere at all. On top of that these functions your professor gave you, is not even reading from static string.

Comment: i don't get what you mean guys @Boris

Comment: Define 'doesn't work', and what you don't understand about `readLine()`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider ahh now i see, he wants to set up variables from outside class directly. Wow, i would have beaten crap out of such professor, teaching to use exposed variables to set values directly without getter and setters.

Comment: it doesn't work because I'm not using it well. I don't understand how read() actually reads, how can I make it read something and therefore how can I read a line of a file using it @EJP

Comment: I didn't  ask you why it doesn't work. That's what you're asking us. I asked you what 'doesn't work' *means.* We can't see your computer. At present there is no question here to answer.

Comment: If you read just the first paragraph of the question, I asked for help to understand how " read() " works so I can use it to read the file. I just posted what I did to show that I tried something, for example if I print whatever that was read with "read()" the output is a blank @EJP

Comment: The code you have posted _does not work_. For example, `length` is never incremented but used as an array index; `phrase` is never assigned but expected to be non-null; `letters` and `length` are `static` but referred by as instance members. Whilst none of these are compile errors, there is no way that the code your have presented does anything but one of two things 1) throw an `Exception` or 2) nothing.

Comment: And I asked you what you don't understand, and you haven't answered. Voting to close.

Comment: did you realize that I wrote "read()" and not "readLine()" ? @EJP

Comment: I realise that you wrote `read()`, but it is far from clear from your question that this is the method you don't understand. Is it? And you could have saved some time by adding what you don't understand about it, which is what I asked  you 55 minutes ago.

Comment: Again, I'm asking you about my method read() , because it's the one I have to work with. In my question I wrote that I don't know how to use it in the specific program I'm working on, which is about reading a file, I see the method read() puts characters into a char array, but I don't know how to write the code so it can be used for reading a file. @EJP